# View subdomain on cpanel without domain

Tags: domains, subdomain, cpanel

I've a cPanel/WHM with some clients.

On cPanel, with an domain you just need create subdomain (`mySub.myDomain.example`) and go on that for view website.

But, how I can do that for clients without domain pointing to my cPanel servers.

Like:
For view client website without domain, you use:
`http://cPanelServerIP/~clientAccount`

And how for subdomains?

Comment: Do you have a domain of your own for creating subdomain sites for clients?